# jquery animate zoom function in asp .net c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

i'm working with jquery and the animate function to do a zoom button to a div, with chrome works fine but with ie8 works to a 50 % because i do a click and does the zoom, i do another click and comes back to the original size, do another click and does the zoom again.

My div guide contains others div's so basically what i have to do is a zoom like a pdf zoom, i.e. the adobe reader zoom to a pdf.

Here is the aspx code of the buttons:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="~/Images/zoom_in.png" OnClientClick="zoom(1); return false;" runat="server" Height="28" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" ImageUrl="~/Images/zoom_out.png" OnClientClick="zoom(2); return false;" runat="server" Height="28" />
                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" ImageUrl="~/Images/zoom_reset.png" OnClientClick="zoom(0); return false;" runat="server" Height="28" />
```

This is the jquery code:

```
function zoom(type) {
            _targetsize = (type == 1) ? _targetsize * 1.2 : (type == 2) ? _targetsize * 0.8 : 1;
            $("#divGuide").animate({ zoom: _targetsize });
        }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to define the _targetsize variable outside of the function, i.e.

```
var _targetsize = 1;
function zoom(type) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved the problem with the version of jquery-1.7.2.min.js and the following line to the load of the javascript:

```
        jQuery.fx.off = true; //Eliminating the Jquery effects it does everything all right on IE8
```